# How to combine object binding keys and with the type declarations?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way of combining object binding keys and with the type declaration?

Right now I am doing this

```
export const useSignOut = ({
  authState,
  authToken,
  setAuthState,
  setAuthToken,
}: {
  authState: AuthState;
  authToken: OAuthToken | null;
  setAuthState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<AuthState>>;
  setAuthToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<OAuthToken | null>>;
}) => {
...
}
```

but I want to avoid repeating myself with the declarations after.

I can't find it in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get around duplicating the property declarations entirely, but if you have an object type with those properties, you can use that as the parameter type.

Answer (score 2):

Not with destructuring the argument like that, no.

You could define the type somewhere else, if it's at all reused.

```
import { MyTypeHere } from './somewhere'
export const useSignOut = ({
  authState,
  authToken,
  setAuthState,
  setAuthToken,
}: MyTypeHere) => {
...
}
```

Or you could avoid the destructuring altogether:

```
export const useSignOut = (options: {
  authState: AuthState;
  authToken: OAuthToken | null;
  setAuthState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<AuthState>>;
  setAuthToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<OAuthToken | null>>;
}) => {
  console.log(options.authState)
}
```

Or do it like you already are. And I think that's pretty much all your options.